# Structures and functions(passing by reference)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, structure

Please guide me on this code, I want to store list of 5 data using array and function, this is a piece of code of mine, but this is giving me an error ("33"):

```
Cannot convert `ABC (*)[5]' to `ABC*' for argument `1' to `void pass(ABC*)'
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ABC{
   char name[20];
   int phone;
   char address[20];


   };

   void pass(ABC *abc){

  for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
        cout<<"Enter name"<<endl;
        cin>>abc[i].name;

        cout<<"Enter phone"<<endl;
        cin>>abc[i].phone;

        cout<<"Enter address"<<endl;
        cin>>abc[i].address;           

        }

 }

 int main()
 {
ABC abc[5];

   pass(&abc);    

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're passing by reference (other than `endl` and `abc[i].phone`).  What you're doing is more correctly called "pass-by-pointer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pass(&abc[0]);` or `pass(abc);` to get a pointer to the first element in the array. Otherwise if you use `&abc` alone you get a pointer to a whole array[5] not the elements inside the array.

Comment: Not quite the right explanation. `&abc` gets a pointer to the array, whereas passing `&abc[0]` or just `abc` will get a pointer to the first element of the array. Since the parameter is of type `ABC*`, it expects a pointer to an element.

Comment: @sftrabbit: right , i did not think of that way to explain it, i will edit.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not pointers. But they can decay to pointers when you are doing function calls. 
So you can pass your array like this:

`pass(abc);`

Comment: +1 for not making the bogus and indefensible, yet very common claim that  *arrays are pointers*!